# Does snappy core work on raspberry pi 3B+

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I have got a raspberry pi 3B running canonical's snappy core on it.
The new raspberry pi 3B+ is out. Before buying it(would like to use one of it's new features) I would like to know if anyone already runs snappy core on his 3B+

If so please add a link to instructions on how to install

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This page
https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/raspberry-pi-3-b-plus?src=raspberrypi#description
Says that it does work

Comment: This is the first time i saw, where it was explicitly mentioned for a 3B+. I try to borrow a 3B+ from a friend and test if it works out.